# Is it possible to override a route handler in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, routes

Say a template application is created with Symfony2. It contains a product description page and the route is created/handled as following:

```
class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/product/{id}")
     */
    public function showDecription($id)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Custom applications are created based on the template application. In other words, the template application provides 'a default value'.

Is it possible to override the route handler in a custom application without modifying the code of the template application? If the route needs to be declared in a different way in the template application in order to be overridable, that's ok. How should one proceed in this case?

Comment: What do you mean by "application"? If you mean complete Symfony application and want to override it's route by the route from another application, then you need to setup your webserver for that. Symfony installations are independent.

Comment: The custom application would import code from the template application. Only one application is deployed: the custom application.

Comment: How do you "import code"? Copy / Paste?

Comment: I was thinking about creating a bundle or an app which would be imported via Composer or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Symfony guide](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html) has the following information on overriding a route:

> **Routing**
>
> Routing is never automatically imported in Symfony. If you want to
>   include the routes from any bundle, then they must be manually
>   imported from somewhere in your application (e.g.
>   app/config/routing.yml).
>
> The easiest way to "override" a bundle's routing is to never import it
>   at all. Instead of importing a third-party bundle's routing, simply
>   copy that routing file into your application, modify it, and import it
>   instead.

Answer (score 1):

The main routing file is `app/config/routing.yml`. I suggest you to create 2 more files: `app/config/routing_default.yml` and `app/config/routing_override.yml` and then edit your `app/config/routing.yml` as

```
override:
  resource: routing_override.yml
default:
  resource: routing_default.yml
```

Now in routing default you can add all default applications routes. And in override one - all additional ones.

Also route names in override and default should not be the same. If you want to override route by name you should change the order of includes.

Comment: Are you saying that symfony2 remembers only the last handler defined/configured for a route?

Comment: if you have two routes with the same name - works the last one. if you have two routes with the same path - works first.